# fs.mkdir vs child_process.exec(mkdir) which one is more efficient

Tags: node.js, child-process

I need to create a dir in nodejs using the 'fs' module but at same time the directory can be created using child_process.exec.

I tried looking in the fs.mkdir code and it went down to node_file.cc and I guess it creates a new v8 environment. I am not sure how this works internally.

And looking at nodejs fs docs  - it creates a subshell - which I guess is fork + exec call.

Was not sure which one is more efficient ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always prefer the in-language version.  I am certain that it does not create a shell just to run `mkdir()` on common platforms.

Comment: you mean I should use the fs ?

Comment: @jitenshah: Yes, you should keep "exec" like functions as a last resort only.  Use the fs functions or anything else if you can.